# when I have already maked the field as nullable. It is not parsing the info gracefully. What could be the issue?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

These are my dependencies in **pubspec.yaml**

```
 dependencies:
  //... More code
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  //... More code
  json_serializable: ^3.2.0
```

**Objects used in serialization**

**BaseResponse.dart**

```
part 'base_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(genericArgumentFactories: true, fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, nullable: true)
class BaseResponse<T> {
  @JsonKey(name: 'success')
  final bool success;
  @JsonKey(name: 'data', nullable: false)
  final T data;
  @JsonKey(name: 'message', nullable: true)
  final String message;
  BaseResponse(this.success, this.data, this.message);
  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(
      Map<String, dynamic> json,
      T Function(Object json) fromJsonT,
      ) =>
      _$BaseResponseFromJson(json, fromJsonT);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Object Function(T value) toJsonT) =>
      _$BaseResponseToJson(this, toJsonT);
}
```

**LoginResponse.dart**

```
part 'login_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class LoginResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: 'access_token', nullable: true)
  final String accessToken;

  LoginResponse(this.accessToken);

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LoginResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LoginResponseToJson(this);
}
```

**Repository**

```
class AuthRepository implements WebApi {
  Future<BaseResponse<LoginResponse>> signIn() async {
    //... More code
    BaseResponse<LoginResponse> result = BaseResponse<LoginResponse>.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body), (data) => LoginResponse.fromJson(data));
    // var result = BaseResponse<LoginResponse>.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body), (data) => LoginResponse.fromJson(data));
    print(response.body);
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Error**
[image: Error from logcat]

The error above is from android studio logcat.
I am not sure what the problem is any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding a null check.
I thought because I have nullable annotations on the objects I should not have to add the check.

```
BaseResponse<LoginResponse> result = BaseResponse<LoginResponse>.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body),
        (data) => data != null ? LoginResponse.fromJson(data) : null);
```